# How to set different page size to different pages In Kendo UI Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Hi I have one requirement in Kendo UI Grid pagination.

How to show

1. X items / rows in 1st page
2. X+1 items / rows in 2nd page
3. X-1 items / rows in 3rd page

I have tried bellow code but not worked, it will show 2 items per page because of latest query selection.

```
$("div[kendo-grid]").data().kendoGrid.dataSource.query({ pageSize: 3, page: 1 });
$("div[kendo-grid]").data().kendoGrid.dataSource.query({ pageSize: 4, page: 2 });
$("div[kendo-grid]").data().kendoGrid.dataSource.query({ pageSize: 2, page: 3 });
```

Comment: have you tried to give your grid different id for jQuery selection? otherwise you just changing all grids

Comment: Hi, I have only one grid in document.

Comment: Sorry i mistook the question, that is little bit out of the box i think.

Answer (score 1):

You should use dataBound event to catch page changes.

```
var page = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.page();
```

will give you the current page.

To change page size you can use something like:

```
if (page == 2){
       var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
       grid.dataSource.pageSize(5);
       grid.refresh();
}
```

Comment: This is same as $("div[kendo-grid]").data().kendoGrid.dataSource.query({ pageSize: 2, page: 3 });

Comment: I am looking for a solution, how can i set different pageSize on different page on runtime/dynamically. Why i need this? i should not show grid scroller when there are more rows are there then grid height. For example my grid height is 400px, and 4 rows/items height is 401px then i should move 4th row to 2nd page. this kind of logic should apply to each page.

Comment: It's not the same because it uses dataBound event which is fired each time the page gets changed. You just need to change the condition to something like if (yourGridHeight < pageSize * itemSize ) {grid.dataSource.pageSize(yourGridHeight / itemSize);}